# psql: database "template0" is not currently accepting connections

Tags: greenplum, hawq

We have Installed fresh gpdb database.But,when trying to connect with template0 database.

```
[gpadmin@mdw~]$ psql -d template0
psql: FATAL:  database "template0" is not currently accepting connections
[gpadmin@mdw~]$
```

**We tried to Update the FLAG**

```
template1=# UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template0';
ERROR:  permission denied: "pg_database" is a system catalog
template1=#
```

But,it is not allowing  to Update The FLAG

Comment: Why do you think you need to connect to `template0`? That database disallows connections for a reason.

Comment: Got it. I  will use instead template1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no reason to connect to *template0*. Even *template1* should not be used, because that is the default template for newly created databases. If you create something in *template1*, it will be copied into any new database. That is easy to forget if you use *template1* to connect to the database and then forget to switch databases.

You can use the *postgres* database for connections. That one is not used otherwise.

Comment: If i need to create  new user database for connections . can i use postgres database for it ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the *postgres* database for this.

Comment: About forgetting to switch, just in case: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Adventures_in_PostgreSQL,_Episode_1